# How can i used backpack-for-laravel for multi languages

Tags: laravel-backpack

How can i used backpack-for-laravel for multi languages. can used backpack for multi languages. Currently we do not see multi language option. Can we need extra plugin to used multi language

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use laravel localization for backpack-for-laravel multi language.

also you can use langfilemanager (https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/LangFileManager)

just overwrite the localization from vendor/backpack/base/src/resources/lang to your localization folder. To change localization just use laravel built-in localization. Hope it helps